# In building an app with Rails, what does Postgres require us to do that built-in SQLite 3 doesn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

What kind of additional things does Postgres require us to do beyond initial set-up? For example, bash command

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

doesn't work after I switched to postgres.

So far I have manually inputted "gem 'pg'" in Gemfile, ran bundle to install pg, switched sqlite to postgresql in database.yml, created database with:

```
   $ rails generate scaffold Product \
             title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

(following tutorial), added stuff on migration file, and when I ran rake db: migrate, I got:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: What I haven't done is adding userid and password for postgres. Could that cause this error?

Comment: You should always first do `rake db:setup` : this will create the database if it does not exist yet. But to be able to do that, make sure the database is running of course ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it literally told you what the problem is in the error output, you haven't started the postgresql server. You will have to start psql in your terminal. Here is an easy app to start psql http://postgresapp.com if you are using mac.


Also, here is the link to the documentation on how to start postgresql server. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

Answer (score 0):

please provide more information, your question about rails with postgres is not very clear. Why doesn't rake db:migrate work? What was the error that was showing at the console output etc. Generally, when you setup rails with postgres as the database rails should include the gem 'pg' automatically in your gem file. After that, you should also have a database.yml file which have the adapter set to postgresql. Then you should create a new database for this rails project with rake db:create. And once you have done that, you will want to create some resource/model for your postgres database, hence creating the migration files. It is when you have your migration files that specify which table/column you want in your database for your model/resource that when you run rake db:migrate rails will create these tables in your postgres database.